# High CPU load caused by bot traffic

Tags: googlebot

[image: CPU status]

Google bot crawl rate is every 2 seconds and it creates about 1.0-1.5 CPU load (average of 1 min) on a KVM host and a VM(web server) until the bot stops around 4AM.
If you see the graph, there is not much traffic outgoing through Firewall's WAN interface RE0, less than 1Mbps most of the time.
However when you see the graph of a web server's virtual BR0 interface, it is about 80Mbps most of the time(VM's outgoing interface).

I assume that bot traffic caused high CPU utilization but I don't understand how web server traffic is generated that much (80Mbps) and there is not much traffic on WAN interface.
Feels like I made something wrong on the VM setting. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: monitor your logs.
if a crawler screw your system, i belive its a lowend device. i mean, i ran on 6 cores and 32gb, 22 Containers for webserver and the average load is 0.x till 1.x for normal usage.
If you enabled compression at a  high level i would suggest to reduce that point. but aslong you neither provide the details nor logs, the question is at the current point not on topic

Comment: Thanks for the comments. It's Ryzen 9 5950X with 128GB RAM so it has 32 threads, 45000 CPU Mark. Assigned that web server with 8 VCPU and 12GB RAM and total 3 VMs (each 8 VCPU, 12GB RAM) running in that host (Rocky Linux 8.6).
To simplify that webserver should have about 11000 CPU Mark. The web server running Nginx 1.21.6 and gzip on (comp level 5 and gzip_static is on) so compression wouldn't be a big factor I guess. Do you think it's low end device? Even if it's low end, how that VM affects the host's CPU load? From my understnaind, this host has plenty of power to handle 3 VMs.

Comment: 8 CPU means it can handle Loadlevel 8 with no pain - your currently at 1... why do you care?

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance. I thought 1.0 would be 100% utilization of all the CPUs. Thank you!

Comment: solved? each cpu can handle one load level adding a second is 2 etc. `htop` can be used to see the cpu and ram eater

Comment: Yes. Now I clearly understand how it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be clarification this question

the user seems to had an understanding issue.

on Linux

- is the load level 1 the utilization of one cpu core.
- if you have 6,you can have a load level of 6.

This differs to windows,

- where 100 percent is really the full usage of the CPU on all cores and threads available